# CakePHP hasMany validations - minimum one

Tags: cakephp, database-relations

I have relations like Project hasMany Photos and the simplest validation (require attach) rule for Photo.image.

But when I add Project with one added file is ok, but when i create many input type file, and part with attached files and part without, then my rule doesn't work good.

...because I want require minimum one file, how solution for this?

Project hasMany Photos with minimum one required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it should be model validation, as what you are trying to do is creating a "Project has one to M Photos" relationship between the two. So this validation should be done on the beforeValidate function at the Project model:

**Project Model**

```
function beforeValidate(){
    if( !isset($this->data['Photo']) || count($this->data['Photo']) == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

The rest will be handled correctly by CakePHP's validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

it should be considered as application-level logic not model validation.

force user to upload at lease one photo from controller.

assumes you have multiple upload fields

### View

```
echo $form->input("Photo.0.file", $options);
echo $form->input("Photo.1.file", $options);
echo $form->input("Photo.2.file", $options);
```

### controller

```
    //form submited
    if (!empty($this->data)) {

        $total_uploaded = 0;

        foreach ($this->data['Photo'] as $i => $record) {

            if (empty($record['file'])) { //some field leave blank
                unset($this->data['Photo'][$i]);
                //continue;
            }else{
                $total_uploaded ++;
            }
        }

        //check at lease 1 file
        if($total_uploaded > 0){
            //validate and saveAll()
        }
    }
```